# One XML file with many animation-lists instead of many XML files with one animation-list (Android - Java)

Tags: java, android, xml, animated-gif

I made a GIF from 2 JPGs photos, using the `spin_animation.xml`, according to the relative Android Developers tutorial.
 It works fine. 
**But** I want to change the GIF inside the `ImageView` in my layout. Basically, I want to change it to 50 different GIFs.

Is there a better and less silliest way to do that, instead of creating 50 `spin_animation.xml`, one for each GIF ?
For example, is there a way to use the `id` that I gave to the `animation-list` inside it ?

---

In my `.java` file, in the `onCreate` method, I call the `spin_animation.xml` in order to make a gif the 2 jpg pictures that I have in my drawables.
My `.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);

    // Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
     // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
     ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

     // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

     // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
     frameAnimation.start();

}
```

---

My `spin_animation.xml` file in my `drawable` contains:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/barbellcurl1" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/barbellcurl2" android:duration="1000" />   
</animation-list>
```

---

And at last my `ImageView` in my `.xml` layout:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp" />
```

---

Comment: I kind of don't understand. Is [combining](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89d3f2d158d23b4de273) all the "gifs" into a single long one not an option?

Comment: With this solution, won't all those PNGs/JPGs combined into one GIF?

Comment: I misunderstood you and thought you wanted to show 50 animations in sequence. That could have been done by creating one huge animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create or modify animation drawables at runtime if you like:

```
AnimationDrawable createFrom(Context context, int id1, int id2) {
    AnimationDrawable ad = new AnimationDrawable();
    ad.addFrame(context.getResources().getDrawable(id1), 1000);
    ad.addFrame(context.getResources().getDrawable(id2), 1000);
    return ad;
}
```

Using above, you could do:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
img.setBackground(createFrom(this, R.drawable.barbellcurl1, R.drawable.barbellcurl2));
```

and you should still have the same result.

---

You can also define those drawables in a xml array: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray - the advantage is that you have to write less code and you can now define all your "gif"s in a single xml file.

Using a typed array should work like this:

```
AnimationDrawable createFromArray(Context context, int arrayId) {
    TypedArray array = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(arrayId);
    AnimationDrawable ad = new AnimationDrawable();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ad.addFrame(array.getDrawable(i), 1000);
    }
    array.recycle();
    return ad;
}
```

The content of the XML file would look like `res/values/gifs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="gif1">
        <item>@drawable/barbellcurl1</item>
        <item>@drawable/barbellcurl2</item>
    </array>
    <array name="gif2">
        <item>@drawable/cat</item>
        <item>@drawable/dog</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

And to get a drawable in code you would do `createFromArray(this, R.array.gif1)` etc.

---

The code in `onCreate` in the end would be

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);

     ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

     AnimationDrawable ad = createFrom(this, R.drawable.barbellcurl1, R.drawable.barbellcurl2);
     // OR
     AnimationDrawable ad = createFromArray(this, R.array.gif1);

     ad.setOneShot(false);
     img.setBackground(ad);
     ad.start();
}
```

Comment: about this error what should I do? `The method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type Context`

Comment: woops, that's API level 21 only, `ad.addFrame(context.getResource().getDrawable(id1), 1000);` should work

Comment: I added those 2 lines: `ad.addFrame(context.getResources().getDrawable(id1), 100);`
`ad.addFrame(context.getResources().getDrawable(id2), 100);` and nothing happens. I found [this](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/12/android-tutorial-frame-animation-with.html) solution that is working fine. Do you think it's a bad solution and keep trying yours instead? Because your solution looks a lot more simplier.

Comment: @marialena That's basically the same solution. What means nothing happened? You see the first image but no animation? I've added a more complete example at the bottom, that includes starting the animation etc.

Comment: With the first example I saw only the image, no animation. In the second one, the transition between the 2 images happens only once and it stays in the second JPG.

Comment: Okay I made it. I added this `ad.setOneShot(false);` before the `img.setBackground(ad);` .I edited it in your code so that It will be  the completely solution. Thanks a lot